# How do I know if a chat message is recieved by the server?

Tags: android, xmpp, asmack

I'm creating an Instant Messenger application for Android using XMPP. How can I determine whether the messages that I send are received by the server? Or how do I determine if the message has been sent?

Comment: Hey @oczdref do you have any find  solution of this question

Answer (score 5):

You'll want support for something called [Stream Management](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0198.html), which allows you to get acknowledgement that the server has received the stanzas you sent.  [Smack doesn't have support for this](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-333) yet.

Another option would be [end-to-end receipts](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0184.html), but this [isn't supported either](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-331).

Answer (score 0):

The xmpp protocol dos not uses acknowledgments for messages stanza, only for IQ stanza it will get a return message for acknowledgment. You can check if the connection with te server is still oké by using a ping message. The server should respond to that by a return ping or a error if ping is not supported. Ether way you know your connection is still working and you can presume that your messages are being received.

Comment: This is a bad answer. not reliable.